# What replaces the obsolete property Window.PersistId

Tags: wpf, application-settings

I am using the code at:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15926/Save-and-Restore-the-Location-Position-and-State-o

to persist my XAML window location.

```
#region WindowApplicationSettings Helper Class
public class WindowApplicationSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    private WindowSettings windowSettings;

    public WindowApplicationSettings(WindowSettings windowSettings)
        : base(windowSettings.window.PersistId.ToString())
    {
        this.windowSettings = windowSettings;
    }
```

Unfortunately the code makes use of Window.PersistId which Microsoft have now made obsolete.

> "PersistId is an obsolete property and may be removed in a future
>   release.  The value of this property is not defined."

What would be the best way to replace this property?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which property should be used instead of PersistId.
I found this solution though for persisting the window settings. I didn't try it myself though.

http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2008/11/18/wpf-binding-to-application-settings-using-a-markup-extension/

Comment: Thanks, I did see this but it doesn't work with Maximized windows or when the number of monitors is reduced (i.e. a remote login).

Comment: Ok, I was not aware of that. You might be able use the Uid property. You simply would need to set it on each control.